# Better way to manage data integrity, without having too many composite FK's

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, referential-integrity

I have following tables:

```
class_table (class_id = Auto Incremented Primary Key (AIPK) of this table)
user_table (class_id, user_id (AIPK of this table))
course_table(class_id, course_id (AIPK of this table))

enrollment_table(class_id, user_id, course_id, enrollment_id (AIPK))
```

Now to maintain data integrity and make sure that both user_id and course_id belong to same class_id, I will have to create 2 composite Foreign Key's (FK) on enrollment_table e.g.

```
(class_id, user_id) to -> user_table
(class_id, course_id) to -> course_table
```

With this kind of schema design, if there are more tables involved then number of composite FK's are increasing. So I wanted to know if there is any better way of modeling this kind of schema and avoiding too many composite FK's.

Comment: And by `account_id` you mean `class_id`, correct?

Comment: yep, corrected the typo

Comment: Why is `class_id` included in every other table? Also, why are you worried about composite FKs? Are they considered harmful?

Comment: Hi Simon, class_id is included because a user or course must be attached to 1 and only 1 class_id. Therefore I do not have a join table (or course_class association table) and have kept class_id in those tables directly. My worry about composite FK's are that in some tables I am ending up with 5-6 composite Foreign Key's like this. So am thinking if it would impact the insert/delete performance in those tables (considering that each of those tables (e.g. enrollment) could possibly have millions of rows.

Answer (score 4):

Two composite FKs including the otherwise redundant column `class_id` are probably the most elegant and efficient solution to enforce that users can only enroll in courses of their class. I see no better alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Erwin, I also suspected the same based on my limited knowledge of DB design. I just wanted to validate my knowledge as this is my first foray into DataBase design.